# Is it possible to detect empty GeoTIFF blocks without reading them when `SPARSE_OK=True` in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'd like to quickly skip empty sparse blocks of a GeoTIFF file when iterating through all the pixels in the raster. The [GeoTIFF Sparse File Documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#sparse-files) says that empty blocks have an offset and and byte count set to 0. So it seems to be it's possible to detect if a block is empty without needing to call through to `band.ReadAsArray`.

Is it possible in the Python GDAL API to detect if a block in a band is sparse (i.e. has offset and byte count set to 0)?

Comment: the `SPARSE_OK` option seems to be for writing GeoTiffs and the tiles might refer to the internal tiff tiles of the GeoTiff. My take on it is it was designed with the aim of reducing storage space. I could be wrong on both counts.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking into any way I can figure this out using either the GDAL CLI (ideally) or Python.